# How does only numbers in URL resolve to a domain?

Tags: url, dns, domain-name

I've been seeing some examples such as `http://38263628` that resolves to a legitimate website `https://example.com`

When doing dig or nslookup on 38263628, it returns me NXDOMAIN.

How does the redirection or resolution work?

For data protection reasons, I can't give the actual numbers and domain it resolves to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We usually write IP addresses as four dot-separated numbers like **12.34.56.78** but the address is just a number and it can be written in other ways.  For example, **12.34.56.78** can also be written as **12.34.14414** or **12.2242638** or **203569230** or **0xc22384e** or **0xc.0x22.0x38.0x4e**.

The four-dot-separated form is effectively a base-256 representation of the number, so to convert from a single large number **N** into the four-dot-separated form **A.B.C.D** you would calculate these four values:

```
A = N / 256 / 256 / 256
B = N / 256 / 256 % 256
C = N / 256 % 256
D = N % 256
```

So your **38263628** is equivalent to **2.71.219.76**

`dig` and `nslookup` don't work with plain numbers because they treat their arguments as strings, even when the arguments are known to represent IP addresses.  (For instance, `man dig` says that the `-x` option requires an address in the four-dot form.  That's because `dig` just wants to treat it as a string that can be split on the dots and rearranged into a `in-addr.arpa` query.)

However, most commands that convert their arguments into actual IP address numbers will accept any of the number formats.  Try it with `ping` (which will helpfully show the address in four-dot format when it shows its results):

```
$ ping 203569230
PING 203569230 (12.34.56.78): 56 data bytes
...
```

That also gives you an easy way to convert any number into four-dot form -- just give the number as an argument to `ping` and let it do the conversion for you.